# Cannot modify a bean of type User that is in a readonly bundle

Tags: gosu, guidewire

I've added a new field to `user.etx` called `LastLoggedIn_Ext`. But getting an error when trying to write to it:

> Cannot modify a bean of type User that is in a readonly bundle

My code:

```
user.Ext_LastLoggedIn = Date.Now
```

Is there a way to bypass read only bundle so that I can save the time the user last logged into PolicyCenter in the user.etx table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add it to writable bundle, for example

```
gw.transaction.Transaction.runWithNewBundle(\bundle -> {
      var writableUser = bundle.add(user)
      writableUser.Ext_LastLoggedIn = Date.Now
    })
```